# StackOverFlow error for QuickSort Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort

I am getting a StackOverflowError for this code. It says lines 184/185, which is where I initialize the split position (see below) and call the first recursive quickSort method. I can see that the code is having trouble exiting from the recursion, but I'm not sure where that is happening. Each time I call quickSort, it is on a smaller partition.

```
import java.util.*;

public class java2{

public static int MAXINT = 10000;
public static int[] intArray = new int[MAXINT];
public static int index;
public static long comparisons;

public static void main(String[] args)
{       
    System.out.println("SORTING ALGORITHM: Quicksort");
    // Create a random array of integers and sort using the CombSort algorithm
    // Print the number of items and comparisions

    for(index = 10; index <= 10000; index = index * 10)
    {
        if (index == 10)
            for(int i = 0; i < index; i++)
                System.out.print(intArray[i] + " ");
        comparisons = 0;
        generate(intArray, index);
        quickSort(intArray, 0, index - 1);
        output(comparisons);
    }
}

// Generate an array of random values between 0 and 10000
public static void generate(int[] valueArray, int count)
{
    Random generator = new Random();

    for(int temp = 0; temp < count; temp++)
    {
        valueArray[temp] = generator.nextInt(MAXINT) + 1;
    }
}

// Print the number of values in the array and the number of comparisons
public static void output(long count)
{

    System.out.println("Number of values in array: " + index);
    System.out.println("Number of comparisons required: " + count);
    System.out.println();
}

//Swap the given values and then assign them to the correct place in the array 
public static void swap(int[] value, int i, int j)
{
    int temp = value[i];
    value[i] = value[j];
    value[j] = temp;        
}

//Implement Quicksort algorithm
public static void quickSort(int[] value, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    int r = endIndex;
    int l = startIndex;
    int s;

    if (l < r)
    {
        s = partition(intArray, l, r);
        quickSort(intArray, l, s - 1); // StackOverflowError here
        quickSort(intArray, s + 1, r);
    }
}

//Partition an array into two parts
public static int partition(int[] value, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{       
    int r = endIndex;
    int l = startIndex;
    int p = value[l];
    int i = l;
    int j = r + 1;

    while(i < j)
    {
        while(value[i] < p)
        {
            i++;
            comparisons++;
        }

        while(value[j] > p)
        {
            j--;
            comparisons++;
        }

        swap(value, i, j);
    }

    swap(value, i, j);
    swap(value, l, j);

    return j;
}
} // end main
```

Comment: You could compare your version with working one: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/23quicksort/Quick.java

Comment: Try to find a very short example where it crashes and compare partial sorted results with what you would expect when you perform the quicksort by hand.

Comment: if your algorithm works for short arrays, you might simply need to increase your stack size. (For real world applications you might consider a non recursive version of QuickSort to avoid the stack probelmatic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By restructuring the partition method, the problem has been fixed:

```
    public static int partition(int[] value, int p, int r)
    {
            int x = value[p];
            int i = p - 1;
            int j = r + 1 ;

            while (true)
            {
                    do
                    {
                        j--;
                        comparisons++;
                    }
                    while (value[j] > x);

                    do
                    {
                        i++;
                        comparisons++;
                    }
                    while (value[i] < x);

                    if (i < j)
                    {
                        swap(value, i, j);
                    }
                    else
                            return j;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few things to get you started with debugging.

You haven't posted your `swap`, but it's almost certainly incorrect. The way you're using it, its prototype would be `void swap(int, int, int, int)` which means it cannot have any effect on the `value` array. Try something like this:

```
public static void swap(int[] value, int i, int j) {
    int temp = value[i];
    value[i] = value[j];
    value[j] = temp;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
swap(value, i, j);
```

Next, get the length=10 case correct. Print out the full array before and after sort, verify that the output is correct. When I run your code on an all zero array I get an infinite loop.

Next, if you're still having problems, add print statements!

Comment: I have updated my swap method to how you described, and I added a print statement for the array of 10 elements, and it works for 10. Immediately following that, though, is the StackOverflowError again. It does not work for the next iteration, which is 100 elements. I will keep looking, but I'm not sure what changes between 10 and 100 elements, besides the actual number of elements of course, which shouldn't have an effect on anything.

Comment: The code you have posted does not reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have updated the code in the original question to reflect what is giving me the error.

Comment: No you haven't. You just added the swap function. Copy/paste that into a .java file and see what you get.